# Facebook SDK, overriding header requirement

Tags: php, facebook

I have written a function that fetches a Facebook photo albums and image details for a portfolio website based mainly around images. Now the facebook class requires me to do this before any headers are output on my page.

The function (`fb_get_albums`) fetches data from facebook is stored as a session array. 
Everything works fine, but it takes a few seconds to load, during which the screen is basically blank.

Is there anyway so that I can display my content first, and only then proceed to fetch the data? If I try this, I get the error `'headers already sent...'`

```
<?php
session_start();   
require_once 'classes/fb-sdk/src;  
fb_get_albums( "fb-username" );  
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>....</html>  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could display the page content first and using Javascript SDK, fetch the images and display it. If the fetching process usually takes more time, then display a rotating loader image so as to inform the user that it might take some time to finish. You could create different types of loader using this online tool: [ajaxload.info](http://ajaxload.info/)

If you do not wish to use the Javascript SDK, then try creating a separate page that would do the fetching of images. So, after the page is loaded, when user presses a button or something, issue an AJAX request to fetch the images from the second page.

That is, `page1.php` contains the basic contents of your page with a button. When use presses that button, using AJAX, `page2.php` is accessed, which would output the image locations or other details back to the caller.

BTW, did you tried debugging the code so as to find the delay caused in fetching images?

Also, in your present code, there is a small typo:

```
require_once 'classes/fb-sdk/src/facebook.php';
```

I mean, the path wasn't complete and was missing an ending single quotes character.

Wish you good luck.